# Port 80 after ip table entry not listening anymore

Tags: linux, iptables

I´ve created a nodeJS application which is deployed a linux machine. In order to only allow the use of HTTPS throughout the application, I´ve create some IP-Tables rules to redirect all incomming requests to 443 => 3000 (3000 === application port).

**What I want to achieve:**

1) User enters http domain => https => PORT 3000 (application)

2) User enters https  domain => PORT 3000 (application)

**What I already did:**

Route all incoming traffic to https!

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 443
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp -o lo --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 443

iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3000
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp -o lo --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3000

iptables-save
```

**What is already working:**

For now only scenario 2) is working.

What do I have to do in order to redirect all incoming traffic on PORT 80 to 443 (https) and then to port 3000 (application port)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just do a port 80 to port 443 forward.

You need to return a HTTP redirect (HTTP Status code 301 or 302) so the browser knows that it's talking HTTPS now not HTTP.

You can not do this with iptables, the best way to do this sort of thing is to proxy for the application using something like nginx or apache. This also means that the proxy can handle the HTTPS certificate handling which is again probably better not done in the application.

The following is the start of what a nginx config would look like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name www.example.com;

    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
     listen 443;
     listen [::]:443;

     server_name www.example.com;

     //SSL cert stuff goes here
     ....

     location / {
           proxy_pass http://nodejs.server:3000/;
     }
}
```

Comment: Ah okay, I wasn´t aware of this. Thanks for you answer!